# Jumble solving program crashes on run

Tags: c, arrays, struct, io

I'm working on a program for my Intro to C class that requires me to write a program that solves jumble puzzles (you know, those anagram puzzles you see in the newspaper), based on a dictionary text file that my professor gave us. It alphabetizes words from the dictionary, takes in jumbles from a text file (called "jumble.txt"), alphabetizes those, then runs a string compare to find a match. I've got all the code written, but it immediately crashes when I try to run it, and I can't figure out why. I thought maybe the Stackoverflow users might be able to help me out here.

Here's the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 6
#define MAX_NUM_WORDS 30000

typedef struct {
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    char sort[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
} jumble_type;

void bubblesort(char letters[], int length);


int main () {
    int words, jumbles;
    int j, q;
    jumble_type list[MAX_NUM_WORDS];
    jumble_type list2[MAX_NUM_WORDS];


// Creating file pointers
FILE *ifp;
FILE *ifp2;

//Opens Jumble and dictionary files and reads the info from them
ifp = fopen("jumbledct.txt", "r");
ifp2 = fopen("jumble.txt", "r");

//Assigns the value of "words" to the first line of jumbledct.txt
fscanf(ifp, "%d", words);

//Assigns the value of "jumbles" to the first line of jumble.txt
fscanf(ifp2, "%d", jumbles);

// Reads the words from the dictionary into the "word" section of our
// list structure.
int i;
for (i = 0; i < words; i++){
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", &list[i].word);
    strcpy(list[i].sort, list[i].word);
    bubblesort(list[i].sort, strlen(list[i].sort));
    printf("%s\n", list[i].sort);
    }

//Reads from Jumble.txt
for (i = 0; i < jumbles; i++){
    fscanf (ifp2, "%s", &list2[i].word);
    strcpy(list2[i].sort, list2[i].word);
    bubblesort(list2[i].sort, strlen(list2[i].sort));
    //printf("%s\n", list2[i].sort);
    }

for(j=0;j<jumbles; j++){
        printf("JUMBLE PUZZLE # %d: %s\n", j+1, list2[j].word);


    int x=0;

for (q = 0; q < words; q++){



        if(strcmp(list2[j].sort, list[q].sort)==0){

            printf("%s\n", list[q].word);
            x++;
        }
}
 if (x == 0){
            printf("Sorry, this puzzle has no solutions. \n\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

}


return 0;
}

void bubblesort(char letters[], int length) {
char temp;
    int x, y;
    for(x = 0; x < length; x++){
        for (y = x; y < length; y++){
            if (letters[x] > letters[y]){
                temp = letters[y];
                letters[y] = letters[x];
            letters[x] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Use a debugger (or even add some printfs) to get an idea where it is crashing.

Comment: Your comments are off; you're assigning whatever `int` can be scanned in `jumbledct.txt` to `words`, not the other way around. (Alternatively, they can read 'assign the **name** of "words" to...') Also, @Nick Atoms is correct: you need to pass `*scanf` pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My C is a little rusty, but shouldn't the third argument to the fscanf function be an address (like &words and &jumbles)?

Comment: That was it, I feel so incredibly stupid now. Thank you for pointing it out.